# didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: and asynchronous data updates?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, background, push-notification, updates

I periodically call several asynchronous RESTful services when the app is running to keep certain data up to date. In addition, I'd like to be able to perform such data update when receiving a push notification intended for that, so I've enabled the background mode for remote notifications and implemented the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` delegate method.

Now my problem is: since my data update performs asynchronous calls to several Web Services, and according to documentation the `completionHandler` of the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method must be called, how could I handle this? Or have I to implement a synchronous version of the data update?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to do synchronous calls to data update web service. Just call `completionHandler` when ever your task gets completed. Basically you will get only 30 seconds to do your updating work. On successful update just call `completionHandler`

Look at following eg.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    // Here write logic as per your requirements, check userInfo for notification data

    // Following is http call for updation

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:30.0];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"RESPONSE From Server: %@", response);

        // Do any updation work

        // Finally call comletionHandler
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the point is I don't know how to make the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method wait until the data update finishes to call the `completionHandler`...

Comment: Thanks. I have several `NSMutableURLRequest` objects and a `NSURLConnection` for each of them... how could I wait for the end of all the connections in this case?

Comment: ok then you need to make it synchronous, no other option and on last call success call completionHandler. But you will get only 30 sec to do all this updating. Finally after 30 sec os will forcefully call completionHandler.